# VB.NET Disable ListView without setting the Enable property to false

Tags: vb.net, listview

Is there a way to disable ListView without setting the enable property to False. Essentially, to capture and ignore any mouse clicks or keyboard inputs.
VB2013.

Comment: remove the event handlers or set a IgnoreStuff flag where you exit sub when it is true and you dont want stuff to happen

Comment: Removing the event handlers wouldn't suppress the **default** behavior of the ListView.  You'd have to suppress mouse events and keyboards events by either inheriting from the ListView or trapping them with IMessageFilter.  You'd also have to prevent the ListView from getting **focus** via the Tab and/or Arrow keys from other controls.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternate approach...

Have the ListView draw itself to a Bitmap and display that in a PictureBox that takes the place of the ListView.  Swap the two controls as necessary:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private pbListView As PictureBox
    Private ListViewDisabled As Boolean = False

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If Not ListViewDisabled Then
            pbListView = New PictureBox
            Dim bmp As New Bitmap(ListView1.Size.Width, ListView1.Size.Height)
            ListView1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, New Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height))
            pbListView.Image = bmp
            pbListView.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize
            pbListView.Location = ListView1.Location
            pbListView.Dock = ListView1.Dock
            ListView1.Parent.Controls.Add(pbListView)
            pbListView.BringToFront()
            ListView1.Enabled = False
            ListViewDisabled = True
        Else
            ListView1.Enabled = True
            pbListView.Dispose()
            ListViewDisabled = False
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

This will allow you to disable the ListView so it can't get focus (taking care of keyboard input), and lets the PictureBox handle the mouse input suppression.

If you need to capture the ListView with the currently focused item, then you'll have to take an actual screenshot.  This can be problematic, however, since other windows could obscure your window and be captured in the image.

Comment: Works like a charm!  Thank you

Comment: Well almost.  If the window is resized, and the control resized with it, then things fall apart.

Comment: Sure...in that case, when the form is resized, just repeat the process.  "Enable" the ListView, allow it to resize and repaint itself, take the picture, then "disable" it again by putting the PictureBox in front again.

Comment: If this approach is to **kludgy**, which it might be for your scenario, then attempt the approach I proposed in the comments.